# Pointer-reference-class assignment

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, g++

Is there something wrong with the following in terms of syntax for the following scenario:

If I have class Foo and a class Foo1 and my class Foo has a private member of type Foo1:

.h file:

```
class Foo{
  Foo1 *oFoo;
public:
  Foo(Foo1 &Fooy);
}
```

.cc file:

```
Foo::Foo(Foo1 &Fooy){
  oFoo = &Fooy;
}
```

Is the assignment in the above constructor legal? I am new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `oFoo` instead of `Foo`, and the member should be initialized in an initializer list:

```
Foo::Foo(Foo1 &Fooy): oFoo(&Fooy) {
}
```

Otherwise it's fine. Consider making the constructor `explicit` to prevent unwanted implicit casts.

Comment: I found the mistake! It wasn't in the code in the question I posted, but thank yous!